# How to await execution of method

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, api

I have two methods, and I want to await result before executing furder code.
I try with async before func name and await before GetNavigationData(), but no results.
I also try to print values to see what's going on, and expected data should be:

*API method*

*Regular method*

But this is results:
[image]

```
getFlatNavigation(navigation) {
  if (this.navigation.length == 0) {
    console.log(this.GetNavigationData());
    console.log('Regular method');
  }
}

GetNavigationData() {
  let applicationMenuData = new InitializeAppRequest();
  this.http.post(this.appGlobal.BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS + 'api/AppServer/InitializeApp', applicationMenuData).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('API method');
    return res['AplicationMenuData'];
  });
}
```

How to get expected results?

Comment: Sorry which function you want to run first?

Comment: They key concept to such problems, is known as [callback functions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async/await

```
async getFlatNavigation(navigation) {
  if (this.navigation.length == 0) {
    console.log(await this.GetNavigationData());
    console.log('Regular method');
  }
}

GetNavigationData() {
  let applicationMenuData = new InitializeAppRequest();
  return this.http
    .post(this.appGlobal.BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS + 'api/AppServer/InitializeApp', applicationMenuData)
    .pipe(
      map((res) => {
        console.log('API method');
        return res['AplicationMenuData'];
      })
    )
    .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, this works. Now I return the whole bunch of data, but I need only res['AplicationMenuData']. How can I do that?

Comment: @NemanjaAndric you can change what it returns in the `map` callback. Right now it gets only `AplicationMenuData` from the response, but you can change it to `res['AplicationMenuData'][0]`...

Answer (score 0):

`async`/`await` requires you to use `Promise` but since Angular has moved on with Observables, you could simply use that syntax instead.

You could return an `Observable` from the `GetNavigationData` method and then subscribe to it in the `getFlatNavigation` where you're calling `GetNavigationData`

```
getFlatNavigation(navigation) {
  if (this.navigation.length == 0) {
    this.GetNavigationData()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log('Regular method');
      })
  }
}

GetNavigationData() {
  let applicationMenuData = new InitializeAppRequest();
  return this.http.post(this.appGlobal.BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS + 'api/AppServer/InitializeApp', applicationMenuData)
  .pipe(
    map(res => {
      console.log('API method');
      return res['AplicationMenuData'];
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async getFlatNavigation(navigation) {
  if (this.navigation.length == 0) {
    console.log(await this.GetNavigationData());
    console.log('Regular method');
  }
}

async GetNavigationData() {
  let applicationMenuData = new InitializeAppRequest();
  this.http.post(this.appGlobal.BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS + 'api/AppServer/InitializeApp', applicationMenuData).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('API`enter code here` method');
    return res['AplicationMenuData'];
  });
}
```

Comment: `GetNavigationData` should 'await' the http post call... You can check my response.